Aurora Mysql command to set default value - null as an expression

Error 1064 (42000): YOU HAVE AN ERROR IN YOUR SQL SYNTAX;
CHECK THE MANUAL THAT CORRESPONFS TO YOUR MYSQL SERVER VERSION FOR THE RIGHT SYNTAX TO USE NEAR'('null')'

ALTER TABLE delete_audit ALTER COLUMN source SET DEFAULT (null);


ALTER TABLE delete_audit ALTER COLUMN source JSON DEFAULT ('null')

I want to alter the existing json column default value(null) and make it as default value but as an expression. Mysql version is 5.7.12
Anyone know any solutions?

Upgrade to MySQL 8.0 to use the feature of expression defaults. Earlier versions of MySQL did not implement that feature.

when i tired to upgrade this to 8.0 it fails with the error in upgrade-precheck.log as the default values are not given as an expression so thats why tried this.
